# OpenGL ES 2.0 - multipass/postprocessing on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, post-processing

I'm new here and fairly newbie with OpenGL ES 2.0 for android as well. I'm trying to do something very simple but for some reasons i cant get it to work.
Basically im trying to use a framebuffer to do some postprocessing work in the fragment shader and then display it on the screen. Below is a simplified version of my fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D u_Texture0;
uniform sampler2D u_Texture1;
uniform float u_FirstPass;
varying vec3 v_texCoord;

float mytexture2D(sampler2D text0, vec2 coord)
{
    vec4 pixelColor=texture2D(text0, coord.xy);
    return pixelColor.r * 0.299 + pixelColor.g * 0.587 + pixelColor.b * 0.114;
}

void main() 
{    
    if(u_FirstPass==1.0)
    {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0,0.0,mytexture2D(u_Texture0, v_texCoord.st),1.0);
    }
    else
    {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_Texture1, v_texCoord.st);
    }
}
```

The FrameBufferObject class i'm using is:

```
package com.my.cameratesting;

import android.opengl.GLES20;

public class FrameBufferObject {
    public int colorTexture;
    private int frameBuffer;
    private int depthRenderBuffer;

    public FrameBufferObject(){

    }

    public void generate(int w, int h){
           //Generate color texture
           //-------------------------
           int [] id = new int[1];
           GLES20.glGenTextures(1, id, 0);
           colorTexture = id[0];
           GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorTexture);
           GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_REPEAT);
           GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_REPEAT);
           GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
           GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
           GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
           //-------------------------

           // Generate frame buffer;
           //-------------------------
           GLES20.glGenFramebuffers(1, id, 0);
           frameBuffer = id[0];
           GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
           //Attach 2D texture to this FBO
           GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorTexture, 0);
           //-------------------------

           // Generate depth render buffer
           //-------------------------
           GLES20.glGenRenderbuffers(1, id, 0);
           depthRenderBuffer = id[0];
           GLES20.glBindRenderbuffer(GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderBuffer);
           GLES20.glRenderbufferStorage(GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, GLES20.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, w, h);
           //-------------------------

           //Attach depth buffer to FBO
           GLES20.glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderBuffer);
           //-------------------------
           //and now you can render to GL_TEXTURE_2D
           //GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);

           //GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    }

    public void unbind(){
        GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    }

    public void bind(){
        GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
    }

    public int getTextureId(){
        return colorTexture;
    }

}
```

And Finally :

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

    GLES20.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1f);
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgramHandle);
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bmp, 0);    

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    //fbo0 is properly instanciated in my onSurfaceCreated function
    fbo0.generate(mWidth, mHeight);
    fbo0.bind();

    GLES20.glUniform1i(mTextureUniformHandle0, 0);
    GLES20.glUniform1f(mFirstPassUniformHandle,1);
    checkFBOError();

    objects[0].draw(mProgramShader,mMVPMatrix);

    fbo0.unbind();

    //***** THIS IS THE BIT THAT DOESNT WORK AS I WOULD LIKE IT TO*******/

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,fbo0.colorTexture);
    GLES20.glUniform1i(mTextureUniformHandle1, 0);
    GLES20.glUniform1f(mFirstPassUniformHandle,0);

    objects[0].draw(mProgramShader,mMVPMatrix);
}
```

So i was expecting my picture after the 1st pass to show up in blue - which works fine when i dont use any framebuffer and dont intend to run the 2nd pass. Now when i run the second pass, i was expecting the same output since im not doing any modification to my u_Texture1... Instead i get a black screen.
I obviously do something wrong here while binding the texture but im not clear how this ping-pong between textures is supposed to work. I did a lot of googling and couldnt find any explicit example anywhere. So if anyone could help me here, it would be great as i have been banging my head with this for quite a long time now. thks.

BTW, please do let me know, if you need additional details.

Comment: Are you sure that you copied the code correctly? That shader would not compile the way it is.

Comment: Thanks Reto Koradi, and sorry, my bad! the first pass is supposed to call mytexture2D whereas the 2nd pass should call texture2D... The end result after the 2 passes should be (or at least that's what i would like to do) the same as after the 1st pass, ie: my picture in blue.
I have corrected the shader so that it's clearer for everybody who would be keen on helping me with this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not using the texture you produced in the first pass when you render the second pass:

```
GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,fbo0.colorTexture);
GLES20.glUniform1i(mTextureUniformHandle1, 0);
GLES20.glUniform1f(mFirstPassUniformHandle,0);
```

This binds the texture to texture unit 1, but then sets the uniform so that the shader samples from texture unit 0. If you want to use texture unit 1, the call to set the uniform needs to be:

```
GLES20.glUniform1i(mTextureUniformHandle1, 1);
```

There are a few more things that are potentially concerning:

- At least in the code shown here, you never clear the FBO. You need to make sure that you have a `glClear()` call after the FBO is bound.
- I think that this call needs a texture bound first. Also make sure that you have the right active texture unit:

  ```
  GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bmp, 0);
  ```

  You probably don't want to load the texture from a bitmap on each redraw. You should be able to load it once during setup.
- You call the `generate()` method on each redraw. Most of what is in there only needs to be done once during setup.
- The `GL_REPEAT` wrap mode is not guaranteed to be supported for non-power-of-two textures in ES 2.0. Unless your width and height are powers of two, you may want to use `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` to be certain that it will work on all devices.

Comment: thanks Reto Koradi. I've changed everything as suggested and it seemed to work when doing 2 passes. However now im trying to do n passes and it doesnt seem to work??? i have updated the initial code accordingly at the top of the thread. Any help with this would be much appreciated as i havent got a clue on what could possibly be wrong here?

Comment: Please don't edit the question to incorporate the answer. That's not how this site works. Stack Overflow is not a forum, it's a repository of questions and answers. If you make significant changes to the question, the answers become invalid, which defeats the purpose.

Comment: sorry and thanks for rolling this back for me. I guess i have to create another question to expose what is my problem now...

Comment: [opengl-es-2-0-ping-pong-between-fbo-texture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27737246/opengl-es-2-0-ping-pong-between-fbo-texture)